# bitnami/laravel error: Unknown database 'bitnami_myapp'

Tags: mysql, laravel, docker, bitnami

I'm working on a docker project but keep getting a strange error when trying to register a user in my database - something to do with my bitnami/laravel image. The docker project has 4 images. One for Vue.js (my front end), one for Laravel (using it as an API strictly. It uses latest bitnami/laravel image), one for my mySQL database, and one for phpMyAdmin. When I use post man to make a post request to my api/register route, I get the following error:

`Unknown database 'bitnami_myapp'`

Here's a few files that might help with solving the problem:

**docker-compose.yml
**

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  vue:
    image: node:latest
    volumes:
      - ./vue:/app
    working_dir: /app
    command: bash -c "npm install && npm run dev -- --host 0.0.0.0"
    ports:
      - "5173:5173"
    depends_on:
      - laravel

  laravel:
    image: bitnami/laravel:latest
    volumes:
      - ./laravel:/app
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    environment:
      DB_CONNECTION: mysql
      DB_HOST: mysql
      DB_PORT: 3306
      DB_USERNAME: root
      DB_PASSWORD: root

  mysql:
    image: mysql:latest
    volumes:
      - mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: learnAppDB
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:latest
    ports:
      - "8081:80"
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: mysql

volumes:
  mysql-data:
```

**.env (inside my laravel image)
**

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:MkDUovbXcWfO6IStDqti+OaUrP6hpBBb3uVLk+3X3Rk=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost

LOG_CHANNEL=stack
LOG_DEPRECATIONS_CHANNEL=null
LOG_LEVEL=debug

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=mysql
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=learnAppDB
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=root

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
FILESYSTEM_DISK=local
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

MEMCACHED_HOST=127.0.0.1

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailpit
MAIL_PORT=1025
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS="hello@example.com"
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
AWS_BUCKET=
AWS_USE_PATH_STYLE_ENDPOINT=false

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
PUSHER_HOST=
PUSHER_PORT=443
PUSHER_SCHEME=https
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1

VITE_APP_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
VITE_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
VITE_PUSHER_HOST="${PUSHER_HOST}"
VITE_PUSHER_PORT="${PUSHER_PORT}"
VITE_PUSHER_SCHEME="${PUSHER_SCHEME}"
VITE_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"
```

**database.php (inside laravel image - config/database.php)
**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Str;

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Database Connection Name
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify which of the database connections below you wish
    | to use as your default connection for all database work. Of course
    | you may use many connections at once using the Database library.
    |
    */

    'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Database Connections
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here are each of the database connections setup for your application.
    | Of course, examples of configuring each database platform that is
    | supported by Laravel is shown below to make development simple.
    |
    |
    | All database work in Laravel is done through the PHP PDO facilities
    | so make sure you have the driver for your particular database of
    | choice installed on your machine before you begin development.
    |
    */

    'connections' => [

        'sqlite' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlite',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', database_path('database.sqlite')),
            'prefix' => '',
            'foreign_key_constraints' => env('DB_FOREIGN_KEYS', true),
        ],

        'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'learnAppDB'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'root'),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
        ],

        'pgsql' => [
            'driver' => 'pgsql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '5432'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'root'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'root'),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'search_path' => 'public',
            'sslmode' => 'prefer',
        ],

        'sqlsrv' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '1433'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'root'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'root'),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            // 'encrypt' => env('DB_ENCRYPT', 'yes'),
            // 'trust_server_certificate' => env('DB_TRUST_SERVER_CERTIFICATE', 'false'),
        ],

    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Migration Repository Table
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This table keeps track of all the migrations that have already run for
    | your application. Using this information, we can determine which of
    | the migrations on disk haven't actually been run in the database.
    |
    */

    'migrations' => 'migrations',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Redis Databases
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Redis is an open source, fast, and advanced key-value store that also
    | provides a richer body of commands than a typical key-value system
    | such as APC or Memcached. Laravel makes it easy to dig right in.
    |
    */

    'redis' => [

        'client' => env('REDIS_CLIENT', 'phpredis'),

        'options' => [
            'cluster' => env('REDIS_CLUSTER', 'redis'),
            'prefix' => env('REDIS_PREFIX', Str::slug(env('APP_NAME', 'laravel'), '_').'_database_'),
        ],

        'default' => [
            'url' => env('REDIS_URL'),
            'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'username' => env('REDIS_USERNAME'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD'),
            'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', '6379'),
            'database' => env('REDIS_DB', '0'),
        ],

        'cache' => [
            'url' => env('REDIS_URL'),
            'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'username' => env('REDIS_USERNAME'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD'),
            'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', '6379'),
            'database' => env('REDIS_CACHE_DB', '1'),
        ],

    ],

];
```

**AuthController.php
**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\User; 

class AuthController extends Controller
{
    public function register(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|string|min:8|confirmed',
        ]);

        $user = User::create([
            'name' => $request->name,
            'email' => $request->email,
            'password' => bcrypt($request->password),
        ]);

        error_log(print_r($request->all(), true));

        return response()->json(['message' => 'User registered successfully'], 201);
    }

    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'email' => 'required|string|email',
            'password' => 'required|string',
        ]);

        if (!Auth::attempt($request->only('email', 'password'))) {
            return response()->json(['message' => 'Invalid credentials'], 401);
        }

        $user = $request->user();
        $token = $user->createToken('Personal Access Token')->plainTextToken;

        return response()->json(['token' => $token]);
    }

    public function logout(Request $request)
    {
        $request->user()->currentAccessToken()->delete();
        return response()->json(['message' => 'Logged out successfully']);
    }



}
```

**api.php**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\AuthController;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| API Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register API routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider and all of them will
| be assigned to the "api" middleware group. Make something great!
|
*/

Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});

Route::post('/register', [AuthController::class, 'register']);
Route::post('/login', [AuthController::class, 'login']); // Change this line
Route::post('/logout', [AuthController::class, 'logout'])->middleware('auth:sanctum'); // Change this line
```

I have:

- I've ctried the following commands inside of my laravel container in terminal:

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan view:clear
php artisan route:clear
php artisan clear-compiled
php artisan config:cache
```

- I've dockered down, and removed and rebuilt all containers
- I've searched for "bitnami_myapp" in my code. It only shows up in the storage/logs/laravel.log file.

Answer (score 0):

Set db_host mysql in config/database.php

Comment: This line? 'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'). Or should I add a property called db_host set equal to mysql?

Comment: My environment variable for DB_HOST is set to mysql already.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it